# How can I solve "Must declare the scalar variable @cds" sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

For the last three hours. I searched the internet for solutions to my problem. I found some but none of them worked (!?). The error is in the btnAdd Sub. I couldn't use this form of declaration: 'DECLARE @cds SqlDBType.SmallInt because I would get the following error: Statement is not valid inside a method/multiline lambda. I also used their form of declaration http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.insertcommand%28v=vs.110%29.aspx but again... I receive the same error. The commented sections are everything I tried. Maybe you can help me solve this. :)

Updated correct solution:

```
Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click

    con.Open()

    Dim dr As DataRow

    mycmd.CommandText = "insert into studenti(cods, nrmatricol, nume, grupa, datan) values(@cs,@nm,@n,@g,@dn)"

    Dim p1 As New SqlParameter
    Dim p2 As New SqlParameter
    Dim p3 As New SqlParameter
    Dim p4 As New SqlParameter
    Dim p5 As New SqlParameter

    mycmd.Parameters.Clear()

    p1.ParameterName = "@cs"
    p1.Value = Convert.ToInt16(txtCodS.Text)
    mycmd.Parameters.Add(p1)

    p2.ParameterName = "@nm"
    p2.Value = txtNrMat.Text
    mycmd.Parameters.Add(p2)

    p3.ParameterName = "@n"
    p3.Value = txtNume.Text
    mycmd.Parameters.Add(p3)

    p4.ParameterName = "@g"
    p4.Value = txtGrupa.Text
    mycmd.Parameters.Add(p4)

    p5.ParameterName = "@dn"
    p5.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(txtDataN.Text)
    mycmd.Parameters.Add(p5)

    mycmd.Connection = con
    da1.InsertCommand = mycmd

    dr = DataSet1.Tables("studenti").NewRow()

    dr("cods") = Convert.ToInt16(txtCodS.Text)
    dr("nrmatricol") = txtNrMat.Text
    dr("nume") = txtNume.Text
    dr("grupa") = txtGrupa.Text
    dr("datan") = Convert.ToDateTime(txtDataN.Text)

    DataSet1.Tables("studenti").Rows.Add(dr)

    da1.Update(DataSet1, "studenti")

    UpdateUI()


    con.Close()


End Sub
```

Wrong:

```
    Dim da1 As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter

    Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click

        con.Open()

        Dim dr As DataRow
        Dim mycmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand
        //Dim mycmd2 As New SqlClient.SqlCommand

        //mycmd2.Connection = con
        //        mycmd2.CommandText = "select* from studenti"


        //Dim v(4) As Object


        //v(0) = Convert.ToInt16(txtCodS.Text)
        //v(1) = txtNrMat.Text
        //v(2) = txtNume.Text
        //v(3) = txtGrupa.Text
        //       v(4) = txtDataN.Text

        mycmd.CommandText = "insert into studenti (cods,nrmatricol,nume,grupa,datan) values (@cds,@nm,@n,@g,@dn)"

        Dim p1 As New SqlClient.SqlParameter
        p1.ParameterName = "@cds"
        p1.Value = Convert.ToInt16(txtCodS.Text)


        //DECLARE @cds SqlDBType.SmallInt
        //cmd.Parameters.Clear()

        cmd.Parameters.Add(p1)
        //cmd.Parameters.Add("@cds", SqlDbType.SmallInt).Value = Convert.ToInt16(txtCodS.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@nm", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@n", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@g", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@dn", SqlDbType.DateTime)

        mycmd.Connection = con
        da1.InsertCommand = mycmd

        dr = DataSet1.Tables("studenti").NewRow()

        dr("cods") = Convert.ToInt16(txtCodS.Text)
        dr("nrmatricol") = txtNrMat.Text
        dr("nume") = txtNume.Text
        dr("grupa") = txtGrupa.Text
        dr("datan") = Convert.ToDateTime(txtDataN.Text)


        DataSet1.Tables("studenti").Rows.Add(dr)

        da1.Update(DataSet1, "studenti")

        UpdateUI()

        con.Close()

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Please only show us the relevant part of your code.

Comment: What is the exact text of the error?

Comment: Do you have check constraints/triggers etc.?

Comment: @SLaks "Must declare the scalar variable "@cds" ."

Comment: Why do you mix two commands? mycmd and cmd?

Comment: Try change all **cmd.** references to **mycmd.**

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå cmd is an SqlCommand on the Form and mycmd is created in the Sub

Comment: If you do execute mycmd `mycmd.CommandText = "insert into studenti (cods,nrmatricol,nume,grupa,datan) values (@cds,@nm,@n,@g,@dn)"
` please tell me when the parameters are set.

Comment: What i'm trying to say is that you do not create parameters nor populate values for the _mycmd_, though you set this to be the insert command of your adapter `da1.InsertCommand = mycmd`.

Comment: I found the solution. Thanks everyone for trying to help me. :) I will update the code.

Comment: @MoldovanRazvan, How can you get this error `Must declare the scalar variable "@cds"` cause there is no parameter named `@cds` in the code shown.

Comment: Was the problem solved (looks like it)? If yes, please publish your solution as an answer, and accept it ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

@cds variable is set by after that it is removed by `cmd.Parameters.Clear()`.
Just remove this line of code and provide a value for @cds.

Comment: I don't see way this will have any affect what so ever. The collection is empty anyway.